# Standards/specifications for WYSIWYG text editor development

Tags: standards, wysiwyg, theory, specifications

I was playing around with the thought of creating a WYSIWYG text editor from scratch just for fun. As I was getting deeper on the subject , I noticed that I do really know nothing about text editing although I use it every day. Its a much bigger task than I assumed, so I started to search for standards and specifications on the internet, but after hours without any helpful results I feel a bit lost on the topic.

Im mainly interested in the user interaction part. What should happen when a user clicks on the text, drags a selection, presses certain key combinations and so on?

Is there any kind of standard/specification for WYSIWYG GUI functionality editors?

Comment: If you are interested in making the editor accessible, you should check the W3C's [Authoring Tool Accessibility Guidelines (ATAG) 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/ATAG20/).

Answer (score 1):

You can check this spec from W3C https://w3c.github.io/editing/contentEditable.html and the Editor recommendations project by CKSource http://ckeditor.github.io/editor-recommendations/